# How do I click on an image button in WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The button type is image, and the relevant code in HTML code attached. I have entered all the data and clicked on *Apply Now* button, it is not at all saving. But when I try to create it manually, it is saved in less than 15 seconds.

Please find the attached screen shot. [image: QuickApplication.jpg]

The relevant code for the same:

```
//Navigating to Quick Application
driver.get(QAurl);
Thread.sleep(15000);
driver.findElement(By.id("DdlSalesPerson")).sendKeys("Swamy m Kumara");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtFName")).sendKeys("Kumar");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtLName")).sendKeys("Swamy");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtAddress")).sendKeys("434, Main Road, Somajiguda");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtZip")).sendKeys("79081");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtSSN1")).sendKeys("881");
Thread.sleep(15000);
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtSSN2")).sendKeys("72");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtSSN3")).sendKeys("4365");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtDayPhone1")).sendKeys("963");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtDayPhone2")).sendKeys("210");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtDayPhone3")).sendKeys("5478");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("ChkIAgree")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtSignature")).sendKeys("Kumar Swamy");
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Entered all the required fields");
//Reading the value in the image.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("FP_SImg_ID")));
String src = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes['src'].value;", element).toString();
img =src.split("=");
System.out.println("Value retrieved from the Image source: "+img[1]);
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("FP_TxtSImg_ID"))).sendKeys(img[1]);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtEmailId")).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("BtnSubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(35000);
System.out.println("Successfully Applied from the QuickApp");
```

HTML code for the Apply now button:

```
<input id="BtnSubmit" type="image" style="height:33px;width:121px;border-width:0px;" 
onclick="javascript:return validateControls();" src="../Common/Images/HybridQA  
/apply_now.png" title="Submit Here" tabindex="45" name="BtnSubmit">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you measuring the time taken to save?  After you click on the button and selenium has got a response your code then sits there for another 35 seconds before it can do anything again.  What makes you so sure the Thread.sleep() is not causing the extra wait time?

Comment: I have given some time to wait for saving/submitting the Application. Its not saving/submitting in the given amount of time. I am not able to save it because the button type is image, as you can see it in HTML code attached.

Answer (score 3):

**You have 1 minute 25 seconds of Thread.sleep() in your code...**

Remove all the thread.sleep(), if you are waiting for elements to appear do it properly, use an explicit wait:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

To take an example from the page linked above:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Have a look at the ExpectedConditions class to see the available conditions built into selenium, if they don't meet your needs it's trivial to write your own expected conditions.

***-------------------Edit-------------------***

For the record this answer is for the original question that was asked which is quoted below (you can have a look at the edit history of the original question to verify this as well).

> ## Taking long time to save after clicking on Apply Now button using Webdriver in Java
>
> Taking long time to save after clicking on Apply Now button using
> Webdriver in Java. I have entered all the data and clicked on Apply
> now button, it is not at all saving. But when i try to create it
> manually, it is saved in less than 15 seconds. Please find the
> attached screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but the issue is not with the Thread.sleep() method. Here i have asked the question about. After clicking on Apply now button, it is not saving the details and submitting the report. I have used wait for synchronizing the script with the application.

Comment: I answered your original question before you edited it.  Your new question is completely different.  Using an explicit wait to ensure that the image is there before you click on it is still something you should do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons for this problem.

1. One is from the HTML code of 'Apply Now' button, I could see that it shows as "input 
   id='BtnSubmit'", but in your script its written as 
   'driver.findElement(By.name("BtnSubmit")).click();'. 
   Shouldn't it be "driver.findElement(By.id("BtnSubmit")).click()"?; 'name' must be 
   replaced with 'id'.
2. At the end of the script you click 'BtnSubmit', the session might expire immediately after 
   you click that button. This problem usually occurs when you use an older and new version 
   of selenium standalone jar file. See to that you use only the latest version and not in 
   addition to an old version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding your 1st point. it can be anything  'driver.findElement(By.name("BtnSubmit")).click();' or  'driver.findElement(By.id("BtnSubmit")).click();'. Because the attribute value is same for both ID and Name property. please see the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Regarding 2nd point, i am using only 1 version of Selenium Standalone jar file version 2.21.0. As i find some issue with latest version of selenium standalone jar file.

Comment: To check whether its because of 'Apply now' button or with session, try writing some additional lines to the script and check whether still the problem exist. If its because of session try using selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0 which is quiet stable.

Comment: i don't find any 2.28.0 version in selenium downloads

Comment: Try with this link - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar&can=2&q=

Comment: Don't use 2.28.0 it's very old and will not work with the latest browsers (anything before 2.30.0 will not work with FireFox 19).  Use the latest version of Selenium which at the time of writing this is 2.31.0.  The latest version is always available from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: I am getting the same issue even when i run it using 2.31.0 version.

Comment: Have you tried changing your code to driver.findElement(By.id("BtnSubmit")).click(); yet?  An ID has to be unique whereas a name doesn't, the most obvious cause would be that you are interacting with the wrong element.  If that still does not work run the page through a W3C validator to see if the HTML is valid and check that there are no duplicate ID's on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtEmailId")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

after this,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtEmailId")).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
```

and comment,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("BtnSubmit")).click();
```

So your code looks like,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtEmailId")).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("TxtEmailId")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
//driver.findElement(By.name("BtnSubmit")).click();
```

Sometimes it's difficult to handle image buttons because these buttons are activated when all required fields are entered. Make sure you filled all mandatory fields and press enter after entering last field in the form. First try to do it manually. Instead of clicking on button press enter at last input field and use same stratefy with automation.

Update:

Use your own code and replace Thread.sleep() with below method.

Call it like,

```
waitForElementToBePresent(By.id("DdlSalesPerson"), 15000);
```

It waits for next element whichever you pass as argument. It returns true if found or false if not. If element found within the given time it will return true immediately instead of waiting for given time.

```
public boolean waitForElementToBePresent(By by, int waitInMilliSeconds) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        int wait = waitInMilliSeconds;
        int iterations  = (wait/250);
        long startmilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-startmilliSec)>wait)
                return false;
            List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
            if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0)
                return true;
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your answer both using Script and manually. It didn't worked. It is a Onclick=Button Submit event.